# PHP - How to fire HTTP get request on a secured URL (HTTPS)?

Tags: php, xml, curl, https, http-get

I am trying to fire a HTTP GET request on a secured URL which asks for username and password. This is fine when I am using that from browser but I am not sure how to do that using PHP.

I have tried using the two methods:

1) Using Curl as suggested in here: [Make a HTTPS request through PHP and get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187/make-a-https-request-through-php-and-get-response)

2) Using the file_get_contents as suggested in here: [How to send a GET request from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php)

But the first one didn't give me any response back. And the second one gave me the following error:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed
```

And this is my code for the curl:

```
$url="https://xxxxx.com";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

and for the file_get_contents:

```
$url="https://xxxx.com";
$response=file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
```

The URL will return a XML response for a API I am testing. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be confusing access restrictions (eg basic authentication & co) and https - are you sure the server requires https?  And if you need basic authentication, you have to tell curl to give the webserver a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If we focus on the requirement to send a username and password because I suspect that's your main problem, try this

```
$ch = curl_init();

$url="https://xxxxx.com";
// OR - check with your server's operator
$url="http://xxxxx.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
// or maybe 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
// - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753648/problems-with-username-or-pass-with-colon-when-setting-curlopt-userpwd
// check the cURL documentation

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// don't forget to check the content of $info, even a print_r($info) is better 
// than nothing during debug
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response fvu. I have tried your code but still no luck with that. 

And $info is just printing out the text "Array".

Comment: And yes the server requires https. otherwise I am getting a 404 error.

Comment: @meraz are you sure you used `print_r` ?  Because it should either show FALSE (on error) or a full set of variables that help you diagnose the transfer or problems.

Comment: oops sorry my bad. I have used echo instead of print_r. Ok so print_r looks like this:

(
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.05831
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)