# PHP cURL GET request : You are not authorized to access this resource

Tags: php, curl

I am facing varied issue. I am able to get response in POSTman but getting below error while using PHP code.

> You are not authorized to access this resource

code as below:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/xml','Accept: application/xml')); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe wrong username and password? The CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST with GET looks a bit suspicious to me, you can remove that afaik for GET requests.

Comment: In postman, try to see eq.curl request - click Code above Send button and choose curl

Comment: The HTTP response headers would tell us a lot more...

Comment: @DanielStenberg it shows 301 moved temporary

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, different cURL versions behave slightly different and so there is not one valid answer but several approaches that work for different cURL versions.

Here are two suggestions:

From [Problems with username or pass with colon when setting CURLOPT_USERPWD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753648/problems-with-username-or-pass-with-colon-when-setting-curlopt-userpwd)

Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`, or instead `CURLAUTH_BASIC`.

Something that should always work:

If it won't help, add username and password directly into url like `https://user:pass@host.com/path`.

You shouldnt turn off certificate verification, instead, get a valid cert, they are for free using letsencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . base64_encode($password)); //here is the change
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/xml','Accept: application/xml'));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is a really longshot and i know that but i have seen quite a few API's that work like that and since the OP seems not to have the documentation of the API i will post this as an answer in case it helps him solve his issue.

If above does not work try to `base64_encode($username)` as well